# Count results after count at SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the next query that count for my specific value, query results are not perfect and I'm getting see several "MIR_id" that has the same ID but don't see the total of them (I want too)
I tried to add more Count with "With" but it mix up everything.
any idea how can I solve it?

```
SELECT distinct 
request_id

      ,(substring(VwDurationIndicator.RequestDetails,5,6)) as Mir_ID
      ,request_type



      ,count(vpo_number) as Number_of_source

  FROM vortex_hvc.dbo.VwDurationIndicator

 left join vw_public_request_material_location_mir on (substring(VwDurationIndicator.RequestDetails,5,6)) like vw_public_request_material_location_mir.material_request_id

     where  ( DateDiff(hh,CreatedTime, getdate()) < 6)

   and request_type like 'MIR' AND SITE LIKE 'HVC' 

     GROUP BY VPO_NUMBER,(substring(VwDurationIndicator.RequestDetails,5,6)),request_id,CreatedTime,AssignTime,ClosedTime,request_type,Product,site
```

Query results:

```
request_id  Mir_ID  Number_of_source
152466  334974  0
152467  334979  1
152472  334985  0
152473  334986  0
152475  334994  0
152534  335046  0
152540  335064  1
152540  335064  3
152540  335064  4
152543  335071  0
152546  335075  1
152549  335078  1
152549  335078  2
152549  335078  3
152549  335078  4
152549  335078  6
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Problem here most likely is that you are grouping more columns than it is needed.

Comment: Why do you have `DISTINCT` along with `GROUP BY`?  Why are you grouping by several fields that you don't then use in your `SELECT` clause?  *(`VPO_NUMBER, CreatedTime, AssignTime, ClosedTime, Product, site`)*   That there are so many *irregularities* indicates that the query you have shown is likely to be a poor example of what you ***want*** to achieve.  Instead you should provide some sample data and the results you want from that sample data, along with a description of how you arrived at those results.  *(Showing what doesn't work without explaining how it Should work doesn't help much.)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`select distinct` is almost never needed with `group by`.  You should be aggregating (in general) only by the unaggregated columns in the `select`.  So:

```
select request_id,
       substring(di.RequestDetails, 5, 6)) as Mir_ID
       request_type,
       count(vpo_number) as Number_of_source
from vortex_hvc.dbo.VwDurationIndicator di left join 
     vw_public_request_material_location_mir rml
     on substring(di.RequestDetails, 5, 6)) = rml.material_request_id
where DateDiff(hour, CreatedTime, getdate()) < 6 and
      request_type = 'MIR' and SITE = 'HVC' 
group by request_id,
         substring(di.RequestDetails, 5, 6)) as Mir_ID
         request_type;
```

Notes:

- Table aliases make the query easier to write and read.
- You should qualify all column names, so it is obvious where the columns come from.
- The `group by` has only the unaggregated columns.
- `select distinct` is no longer needed.
- Spell out date parts when using functions that take them ("hour" instead of "hh").
- I replaced `like` with `=`.  You should use `=` unless you really want to handle wildcards.

Comment: Thanks it looks ok now :).

I have one more question... if I want to count additional column "value" after this query execute how I can do it? for example counting request_id

Comment: @Avi22 . . . I'm not sure.  You should ask another question with sample data and desired results.